# How to update local Parse objects?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

So I am using Parse Server's local data functionality. I have an issue when I try to refresh the local objects where the TableView will freeze when updated. What I understand is that the table view is trying to access objects that are being changed which causes the freeze. The work around would be to fetch the objects and then replace my local objects with the new ones.

Doesn't this miss the whole  point of having local objects though? Isn't the whole point to just have said objects in one place and updating them whenever need instead of fetching new ones and replacing local?

To update all I do is grab each object of the data model and fetch itself.

Been at this issue for 2 days now - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after a session on codementor I (along with a lot of help) figured out what was going on.

Local objects can't be accessed while they are being updated. In my case, the first thing that happened when the user opened the app was to update the local objects but since my `rootViewController (UITableViewController)` accessed that data to display the cells, it froze.

My solution was to instead of updating the local objects, I queried those same objects by object ID and then replaced the local objects with the ones my query returned.